# My mouse keeps turning off, I've no idea what could be a reason

Tags: windows, usb, drivers, mouse, connection

I bought this Legion M300s mouse 6 month ago, and it worked perfectly all this time with my Acer Aspire 7 laptop. Some time ago it started to randomly turn off (the device manager still sees it connected, and there is no Windows sound of something being disconnected). It starts to work again after I plug it out and back in. This happens around every 20-30 minutes, but sometimes it can happen a few times in a row, or not happen in hours. There were no Windows or driver updates before that started to  happen.

Obviously, I tried to troubleshoot it. Here is what I tried to do:

- used different USB-ports;
- deleted and reinstalled different versions of a mouse driver;
- changed the settings of power supply of USB ports and other devices (removed the permission of Windows to turn off the device);
- tested the mouse with other laptops - works fine;
- tested other mice with my laptop - they work fine;
- reinstalled Windows (I used Windows 11 all the time using the mouse);
- tested the mouse in games/while rendering to check if the issue is connected to high CPU/GPU load - the mouse behaves the same way as on the desktop with no programs opened;
- checked all other possible drivers (motherboard, BIOS, etc.) - all up-to-date and didn't change for a long time;
- used different scanning commands in Command Prompt which I found online - neither of them found any issues;
- executed the full Windows Defender virus scan - it didn't locate any.

Also, I've brought the mouse to the service center in the shop where I bought it, since it had a 1 year warranty. After a week they told me that they did not discover any issues with the mouse, however they replaced the CPU of it. After that it worked fine for a day, and then started to turn off again.

Another thing that it doesn't turn off if I don't move it. I have no idea what could be the reason, anybody has any ideas? I would appreciate any guesses. I really like the mouse and wouldn't want to replace it.

Comment: it is a wired mouse, probably a broken wire

Comment: @Yorik I mentioned that I tested the mouse with other laptops and it worked fine, how can it be a broken wire issue? Also, the service center staff would definetily notice if there was something wrong with the wire.

Comment: intermittent wire connections are hard to diagnose reliably but it is the exact bahavior you mention. As far as the shop, if they said they "replaced its CPU" then I would not trust anything they said.

Comment: @Yorik they replaced some main chipset, I'm not sure how it would be called in English. I still don't get it how it would work with other laptops but not mine, if it is a wire issue.

Comment: If you use a USB hub, plug it directly into the computer

Comment: @LPChip I don't, it is plugged directly into one of the USB ports of my laptop.